# Shift elements by one index with memmove

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memmove

I am trying to shift the elements in a dynamically created 3d array by one index, so that each element `[i][j][k]` should be on `[i+1][j][k]`.

This is how my array creation looks like

```
typedef struct stencil{
int ***arr;
int l;
int m;
int n;}matrix;

void createMatrix(matrix *vector){

vector->arr = (int***) malloc(sizeof(int**) * (vector->l+2));
for (int i = 0; i< vector->l+2; ++i) {
    vector->arr[i] = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * (vector->m+2));
    for (int j = 0; j < vector->m+2; ++j) {
        vector->arr[i][j] = (int*) calloc((vector->n+2),sizeof(int));
    }

}
}
```

This is basically what I want to achieve with memmove

```
for(int i = vector->l-1; i >= 0; --i){
    for(int j = vector->m; j >= 0; --j){
        for(int k = vector->n; k >= 0; --k){
            vector->arr[i+1][j][k] = vector->arr[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

for some reason memmove shifts 2 indices.

```
memmove(&(vector->arr[1][1][1]), &(vector->arr[0][1][1]), (vector->l+2)*(vector->m+2)*(vector->n)*sizeof(int*));
```

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) see we can see what you're working with. There are many ways that you could implement `vector`.

Comment: If it's dynamically-allocated, the first dimension should be an array of pointers. Why don't just just shift those pointers, instead of moving all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a dynamic multi-dimensional array like this, the array contents are not contiguous -- each row is a separate allocation. So you can't move it all with a single `memmov()`.

But you don't need to copy all the data, just shift the pointers in the top-level array.

```
int **temp = arr[l-1]; // save last pointer, which will be overwritten
memmov(&arr[1], &arr[0], sizeof(*arr[1]));
arr[0] = temp;
```

I've shifted the last element around to the first, to avoid having two elements that point to the same data. You could also free the old last element (including freeing the arrays it points to) and create a new first element, but this was simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Simply doing this would work (Illustrating in a 3d array)

```
memmove(arr[1], arr[0], Y*Z*sizeof(int));
```

where `Y` and `Z` denotes the other 2 dimensions of the 2d array.

Here `arr[X][Y][Z]` is the `int` array where `X>=2`.

In case of dynamically allocated memory you need to do each continuous chunk one by one. Then it would work.

Comment: This creates the same result as the memmove in my question

Comment: @Schueni1.: This is the way to do. Provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with a higher optimization level (`-O3`). Obtain a direct reference on `vector->arr` instead of forcing dereferencing on every single array access.

Your call to `memmove` looks half correct under the assumption that you allocated `arr` as continuous memory. However, since you said "dynamic", I very much doubt that. Plus the size calculation appears very much wrong, with the `sizeof(int*)`.

I suppose `arr` is not `int arr[constexpr][constexpr][constexpr]` (single, continuous allocation), but rather `int ***arr`.

In which case the `memmove` goes horribly wrong. After moving the `int**` contents of the `arr` field by one (which actually already did the move), it caused a nasty overflow on the heap, most likely by chance hitting also a majority of the `int*` allocations following.

Looks like a double move, and leaves behind a completely destroyed heap.